# How to forward localhost ports from remote server when using tramp?

Tags: tramp

How to forward localhost ports to the remote server when using tramp, like one can do with ssh as follows:

```
ssh -L <local port>:localhost:<remote port> <user_id>@<server_ip_addr>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `~/.ssh/config` file, you could add an entry like

```
Host <server_ip_addr>
     LocalForward <local port> localhost:<remote port>
```